# Regexp for finding tags without nested tags

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regexp which will help to find non-translated texts in html code.

Translated texts means that they are going through special tag:  or through construction: ${...}

Ex. non-translated:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Translated texts are:

```
<h1><fmt:message key="hello" /></h1>
<button>${expression}</button>
```

I've written the following expression:

```
\<(\w+[^>])(?:.*)\>([^\s]+?)\</\1\>
```

It finds correct strings like:

```
<p>text<p>
```

Correctly skips

```
<a><fmt:message key="common.delete" /></a>
```

But also catches:

```
<li><p><fmt:message key="common.delete" /></p></li>
```

And I can't figure out how to add exception for ${...} strings in this expression
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags =).  You should use an html parser instead.

Comment: @notnoop: But that's not HTML, that's JSTL. Although.. I don't know JSTL but if it is well-formed enough then you can use an XML parser.

Comment: I'd really love to see a regexp question involving stuff with angle brackets, where this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags] isn't linked in some comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you properly, you want to ensure the data inside the "tag" doesn't contain `fmt:messsage` or `${....}`

You might be able to use a negative-lookahead in conjuction with a `.` to assert that the characters captured by the `.` are not one of those cases:

```
/<(\w+)[^>]*>(?:(?!<fmt:message|\$\{|<\/\1>).)*<\/\1>/i
```

If you want to avoid capturing any "tags" inside the tag, you can ignore the `<fmt:message` portion, and just use `[^<]` instead of a `.` - to match only non `<`

```
/<(\w+)[^>]*>(?:(?!\$\{)[^<])*<\/\1>/i
```

**Added from comment** If you also want to exclude "empty" tags, add another negative-lookahead - this time `(?!\s*<)` - ensure that the stuff inside the tag is not empty or only containing whitespace:

```
/<(\w+)[^>]*>(?!\s*<)(?:(?!\$\{)[^<])*<\/\1>/i
```

Comment: The latter case is the best! It is not as greedy as former (doesn't match <p><a>something</a></p>, but match just <a>something</a>). The only thing I couldn't figure out how to exclude whitespaces (i.e. not match for '<p> </p>')

Comment: Doesn't it still match `<p><a>something</a></p>`? When it reaches `<a>` it cannot tell if it's inside a tag or not.

Comment: @kemp - No, it fails to match `<p><a` (because 'a' is not a '/') so it advances forward finding `<a>something</a>` and returns its match

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, I thought `<p><a>something</a></p>` should fail completely

Answer (score 1):

If the format is simple as in your examples you can try this:

```
<(\w+)>(?:(?!<fmt:message).)+</\1>
```

Comment: it works better than mine, but still catches <h1><p>hi</p></h1> (here I need only nested 'p' tag) and <p><input /></p>

Answer (score 0):

I've used a simple one like this with success,

`<([^>]+)[^>]*>([^<]*)</\1>`

of course if there is any CDATA with '<' in those it's not going to work so well. But should do fine for simple XML.

Comment: nice, but it doesn't work for tags with attributes like <li class="something">hi</li>

Answer (score 0):

Rewritten into a more formal question:

Can you match

`aba`

but not

`aca`

without catching

`abcba` ?

Yes.

FSM:

`Start->A->B->A->Terminate`

Insert abcba and run it

```
Start is ready for input. 
a -> MATCH, transition to A
b -> MATCH, transition to B
c -> FAIL, return fail.
```

Answer (score 0):

also see

https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

for a discussion of using regex to parse html

executive summary: don't